# Can Remote Desktop connect only 2 monitors when the client has 3 or 4 monitors connected?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, window

I have three monitors (all 1920x1200) connected to my desktop and I would like to RDP into another computer (running Windows Server 2003) and use only two of my three monitors.  The main monitor is used for notification from the LAN like email, build status, etc.

I've tried modifying the `.rdp` file to have a higher resolution (i.e. 3840x1200 ) which sort of works but the bits per pixel goes down to 8 and you have to manually resize the window which means that you need to change it to around 3840x1150.

If I supply `/span` to the commandline it gives me a bit more than 3840 spanned across the three monitors (is there perhaps a limitation of say 4096 for the maximum resolution?).

WORKAROUND: Connect twice to the same computer.

Here's an interesting post from Microsoft: [Remote Desktop Connection 7 for Windows 7, Windows XP & Windows Vista](https://web.archive.org/web/20160126170455/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/08/21/remote-desktop-connection-7-for-windows-7-windows-xp-windows-vista.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

What I do is run VMware worskstation which allows you to toggle between any combination of all, any 2 of three, or a single monitor in full screen. Then I run RDC client within the full-screened to two monitors VM. Works great though it's unfortunate Microsoft doesn't provide a way to do this.

Comment: turtles all the way down.. nice work-around!

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays this works right out of the box with Microsoft's RDP desktop client.
However, you have to edit the rdp-file manually and add the following line:

```
selectedmonitors:s:x,y
```

where x an y has to be replace by the numbers of the screens you'd like to use.
To get a list of your screen numbers execute `mstsc /l`.

Of course you also need

```
use multimon:i:1
```

Detailed description at https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRemoteDesktopFullscreenRDPWithJustSOMEOfYourMultipleMonitors.aspx