How do I configure remote desktop client to extend to only some of my monitors but not all?
I use the remote desktop client on my Windows 10 machine to log into my computer at work. I have three monitors. If I want to extend my work monitors, I have to select "Use all my monitors for the remote session" under the Display tab. And then all 3 monitors are used. But what if I want to extend to only two of my monitors and leave the 3rd one for my local (home) machine?


https://superuser.com/a/1490431/576138 -- General tab > connection settings > save as. > name the file. Right click and  edit with notepad the .rdp file that saves and add the lines in the link. They don't explain the first bit on where the keys go but it is in this file.

Thanks Narzard... what do you call the language the drp file is written in?
